# Color Theme selector for web base app with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm working on a web app and I want to have the user be able to change the theme of the content. I basically need to change the color of css backgrounds, texts and borders. The app has many different classes and Id's, but mainly 4 repeating colors that would need to be replaced.

My questions is:

What would be the most efficient way to change the colors with Jquery?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a class on the root element or body like:

```
<body class="raw_umber">
```

The write your CSS rules base on these classes, for example:

```
.raw_umber h1 {
    color:#7B4A12;
}
.blue h1 {
    color:#00c;
}
...
```

Then use jQuery to change that class.

**EDIT**

```
.raw_umber .some_class {
    border-color: #7B4A12;
}
.raw_umber .some_other_class {
    color:#7B4A12;
}
```

Those are examples of other rules.  But there's no way I could account for every possible rule you need.

Comment: Thank you, but what about background colors or borders?

Comment: I updated that answer, but there's no way I could account for every possible element in your page/app.  The principle is the same no matter how many different elements/styles you want to impact.